# How to return a decimal after using int() function on a string?

Tags: python, int, decimal

Very basic question. If I set products as 3 and parcels as 2, I get 1. How do I have the last line print 1.5, a decimal, instead of simply 1?

```
products = raw_input('products shipped? ')   
parcels = raw_input('parcels shipped? ')  


print "Average Number of products per parcel"  
print int(products) / int(parcels)
```

Comment: print float(products) / int(parcels) or

print int(products) / float(parcels) 

will give your required results...

Answer (score 2):

```
print float(products) / float(parcels)
```

If you want real numbers, use `float`, which represents real numbers. Don't use integers.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 you'll get this automatically.

In Python 2 you can do `from __future__ import division`, then dividing two integers will result in a floating point number.

In either case you can use `//` instead of `/` if you decide you really needed an integer result instead. That works in Python 2 even if you don't do the import.

You can also convert either or both of the numbers to `float` to force a floating point result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full decimal value use the below,

```
from decimal import Decimal
print Decimal(products) / Decimal(parcels)
```